# Toggling ActionBar visibility for SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: java, android

**Method implemented in parent class (`extends SherlockFragmentActivity`)** [(source)](https://github.com/smarek/Simple-Dilbert/blob/master/src/com/mareksebera/simpledilbert/DilbertFragmentActivity.java)

```
ViewPager viewPager; // initialized in onCreate method
public void toggleActionBar() {
    try {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        if (getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
            lp.topMargin = 0;
        } else {
            getSupportActionBar().show();
            lp.topMargin = getSupportActionBar().getHeight();
        }
        viewPager.setLayoutParams(lp);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Toggle of Actionbar failed", t);
    }
}
```

**Call made from one of Fragments in ViewPager** [(source)](https://github.com/smarek/Simple-Dilbert/blob/master/src/com/mareksebera/simpledilbert/DilbertFragment.java)

```
try {
    ((DilbertFragmentActivity) getSherlockActivity()).toggleActionBar();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Toggle of Actionbar failed", t);
}
```

MinSdkVersion is equal 8, ActionBar support is done by ActionBarSherlock library.

Comment: [Is it a bad idea to use printStackTrace() in Android Exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3855187/843804) at Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2):

Three points:

1. `getSupportActionBar()` is called four times within the same method. Store it as a local variable and use the variable four times instead, to improve code cleaniness and readability.
2. When catching exceptions, [be as specific as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083248/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-catch-the-throwable). Catching `Throwable` is a **horrible** idea. **Only catch the exceptions you need to catch** (Which involves neither `Error`s or `RuntimeException`s. You shouldn't even wrap `((DilbertFragmentActivity) getSherlockActivity()).toggleActionBar();` inside a try-catch statement. If you think that something can go wrong (like a `NullPointerException`), *make sure that it doesn't go wrong before you try to do it* (by checking if something is not null for example).
3. If `viewPager` can be marked as `private`, it is good practice to also mark it as `private`.